# Convert dplyr chain into a function

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a column of dates, this will count the number of records in each month

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

samp <- tbl_df(seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-01"), by="day"))

freq <- samp %>%
    filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
    transmute(month = floor_date(value, "month")) %>%
    group_by(month) %>% summarise(adds = n())


freq
# A tibble: 12 x 2
        month  adds
       <date> <int>
 1 2017-01-01    31
 2 2017-02-01    28
 3 2017-03-01    31
 4 2017-04-01    30
 5 2017-05-01    31
 6 2017-06-01    30
 7 2017-07-01    31
 8 2017-08-01    31
 9 2017-09-01    30
10 2017-10-01    31
11 2017-11-01    30
12 2017-12-01     1
>
```

I would like to convert this to a function, so that I can perform the operation on a number of variables.  Have read the vignette on dplyr programming, but continue to have issues.

My attempt;

```
library(rlang)
count_x_month <- function(df, var, name){
    var <- enquo(var)
    name <- enquo(name)

    df %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!var)) %>% 
    transmute(month := floor_date(!!var, "month")) %>%
    group_by(month) %>% summarise(!!name := n())
} 

freq2 <- samp %>% count_x_month(value, out)
```

Error message;

```
 Error: invalid argument type
```

Making this version of the function work will be a big help.  More broadly, other ways to achieve the objective would be welcome. 
One way to state the problem; given a dataframe of customers and first purchase dates, count the number of customers purchasing for the first time in each month.

update:  The selected answer works in dplyr 0.7.4, but the rstudio environment I have access to has dplyr 0.5.0.  What modifications are required to 'backport' this function?

Comment: Where does `floor_date` come from?

Comment: @MrFlick lubridate.

Comment: Don't use var as a name since it is also a base function name.  For summarise the way you are handling the quoting/unquoting won't work, you need to handle the whole expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `quo_name` it

```
library(rlang)
count_x_month <- function(df, var, name){
  var <- enquo(var)
  name <- enquo(name)
  name <- quo_name(name)

  df %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!var)) %>% 
    transmute(month := floor_date(!!var, "month")) %>%
    group_by(month) %>% 
    summarise(!!name := n())
} 

freq2 <- samp %>% count_x_month(value, out)

# A tibble: 12 x 2
        month   out
       <date> <int>
 1 2017-01-01    31
 2 2017-02-01    28
 3 2017-03-01    31
 4 2017-04-01    30
 5 2017-05-01    31
 6 2017-06-01    30
 7 2017-07-01    31
 8 2017-08-01    31
 9 2017-09-01    30
10 2017-10-01    31
11 2017-11-01    30
12 2017-12-01     1
```

See "Different input and output variable" section of "[Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)":

> We create the new names by pasting together strings, so we need
>   quo_name() to convert the input expression to a string.

Comment: this is working on rstudio installed on my laptop, but not on the rstudio professional server I work on. I assume this is a versioning issue..

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by `summarise(df, !!name := n())` and is solved by replacing the second line of the function with

```
name <- substitute(name)
```

The reason, as far as I understand it is, that a *quosure* is not only its name, but it carries with it the environment from where it came. This makes sense when specifying column names in functions. The function must know from which data frame (=environment in this case) the column comes to replace the name with the values.

However, `name` shall take a new name, specified by the user. There is nothing to replace it with. I suspect if using `name <- enquo(name)`, R wants to replace `!!name` by values instead of just putting in the new name. Therefore it complains that on the LHS there is no name (because R replaced it by values(?))

Not sure though if `substitute` is the ideomatic "programming with dplyr" way though. Comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataframe showing customer IDs and first purchase dates:

```
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-01"), by="day")
dates_rep <- c(dates,dates,dates)
cust_ids <- paste('id_', floor(runif(length(dates_rep), min=0, max=100000)))
cust_frame <- data.frame(ID=cust_ids, FP_DATE=dates_rep)

head(cust_frame)
```

[image]

Use the plyr package to aggregate by FP_DATE:

```
library(plyr)
count(cust_frame, c('FP_DATE'))
```

Therefore, given a dataframe of customers and first purchase dates, we get a count of the number of customers purchasing for the first time in each month.

[image]

You can extend this to aggregate across any number of features in your dataset:

```
count(cust_frame, c('FP_DATE', 'feature_b', 'feature_c', 'feature_d', 'feature_e'))
```